# How to add get an array of modules I import with from x import *?

Tags: python, module

I have a directory `plugins` containing plugins of my application, each plugin is a python file which defines a method `handle` in it. the structure is like:

```
- main.py
- plugins
      - hello.py
      - foo.py
      - bar.py
      - ...
```

Now I'd like to import all modules in `plugins` in `main.py` with:

`from plugins import *`

however, I want to get a list of the modules, so I can loop through it, like:

```
for plugin in plugin_modules:
    plugin.handle(data)
```

How could I do this?

Comment: If there's a function called `handle` in `hello.py`, you won't be able to call it with `import *` anyway- you can't do `from plugins import *; hello.handle(data)` (try it). You have to do `from plugins import hello; hello.handle(data)`

Answer (score 1):

Try `pkgutil`:

```
import os.path, pkgutil
import mypackage

package = mypackage
mods = [n for _,n,_ in pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname(package.__file__)])]

for mod in mods:
    package.__dict__.get(mod).handle(data)
```

Comment: how could I use the name to get the real module?

Answer (score 0):

simple but won't get everything:

```
import plugins

for i in range(len(plugins.__all__)):
    getattr(plugins, plugins.__all__[i]).handle(data)
```